# I want to add and print only 6 items with the Array list

Tags: java

If today is Monday, its number is 2. And I needed to add next 5 working days which should not include Sunday(holiday) into the array list.
I'm new to coding, and I'm studying 9th Standard. Please help me in coding. Thanks in !

```
 public class WeekView {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     List<Integer> daysList = new ArrayList<>();
     int m = 6, dayOfWeek = 6;
     for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
         if (dayOfWeek == 1) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             dayOfWeek++;
         } else if (dayOfWeek == 2) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             dayOfWeek++;
         } else if (dayOfWeek == 3) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             dayOfWeek++;
         } else if (dayOfWeek == 4) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             dayOfWeek++;
         } else if (dayOfWeek == 5) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             dayOfWeek++;
         } else if (dayOfWeek == 6) {
             daysList.add(dayOfWeek);
             for (int j = 1; j < dayOfWeek; j++) {
                 daysList.add(j);
             }
         }
     }
     System.out.println("Day Num :" + daysList);
 } }
```

and my current output is

```
Day Num :[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But I need output like given below

```
  6,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Take the loop out of your last `if`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the reply, Just now I tried as you advised, but it's not  working. I got the output like this Day Num :[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: the documentation of `List` helps: method [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) for example

Comment: Then you didn't change anything. Since that was your original output. You don't need a loop to add `6,1,2,3,4,5` to a `List` anyway. I would just do `List<Integer> daysList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I give weekday as 1, then our code should print from 1 to 6.if we give 2 means, our code should print 2,3,4,5,6,1 like this I need

Comment: Fascinating. The only problem with your original code was the loop in your last `if` statement. You should try removing that loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch after removing loop, I got output like this Day Num :[4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]

Comment: The problem with his original code is not his last if statement, the problem is that there is the exact same code in all his if statements which make them pointless... @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Can you Solve it , if you know which is pintless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Integer> daysList = new ArrayList<>();
int day = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    daysList.add(day);
    day++;
    if(day > 6) day = 1;
}

System.out.println("Day Num :" + daysList);
```

Where :

- `i` iterates over the number of working days
- `daysList.add(day)` to add the current day to the list
- `days++` to go to the next day at each loop iteration
- `if(day > 6) day = 1` to go back to monday if `day` reaches sunday

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by explaining why this code answers OP's question.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, fixed it. It's very basic stuff though, I'm sure even as a beginner he would've understood it.

Comment: Yes, probably, but code-only answers are highly discouraged here. I just warned you to prevent your answer from getting downvotes.

Comment: @oguzismail True, and that's very kind of you :) Will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add to `day` while you increment, you can use the modulus operator to remove the `if` check. Like,

```
int day = 6;
List<Integer> daysList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    daysList.add(1 + ((day + i - 1) % 6));
}
System.out.println("Day Num :" + daysList);
```

or in Java 8+ using an `IntStream` to generate the values like

```
int day = 6;
List<Integer> daysList = IntStream.range(0, 6).map(i -> 1 + ((day + i - 1) % 6)).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Day Num :" + daysList);
```